# how to gfxdraw in a subclass of pygame.Surface?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

am I subclassing `Surface` the wrong way? The error says that `gfxdraw.aacircle()` requires a `Surface` as first argument, but I can't figure out how to do that.

runnable code and exception below:

```
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import gfxdraw

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

class basicButton(pygame.Surface): # basic surface for buttons
    def __init__(self, size, radius):
        pygame.Surface.__init__(self, size=(size, size))
        self.fill(BLACK)
        # anti-aliased outline
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(self, radius, radius, radius, WHITE)
        # color filled circle
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(self, radius, radius, radius, WHITE)
        # set black to be transparent
        self.set_colorkey(BLACK)

# make an instance
quitButtonSurf = basicButton(25, 12)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

while True:
    screen.blit(quitButtonSurf)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

throws exception:

```
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(self, radius, radius, radius,  WHITE)
  TypeError: surface must be a Surface
```

Comment: I don't have experience working with making class objects of the surface type, I generally work with sprites. That being said, have you considered treating it as a normal object and simply assigning it a surface for an image? Then you could pass in that surface for the draw function.

Comment: thanks for answering. i thought about what you said and I'm going to try it, but still don't get why this isn't working. I also work with sprites, but i'm making all sprite.image s from a Surface costructor, as all graphics are similar and code-generated, is this bad practise?

Comment: I'm a self taught solo developer who doesn't have the advantage of peer review, so I wouldn't be the one to comment as to whether something is bad practice or not. I am thinking you'd be better served with a function that calls pygame's surface class though. Not because what you're doing is a bad idea necessarily, but because it's something we know that works. The only thing to really change would be the first few lines of your current class code. You can perform all other functions on the instance of the surface class that you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't EXACTLY what you were looking for, but it should work.

```
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import gfxdraw

pygame.init()


BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

class basicButton: 
    def __init__(self, size, radius):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size)) # as per your example, assuming a square
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(self.image, radius, radius, radius,  WHITE)
        pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(self.image, radius, radius, radius,  WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)


quitButtonSurf = basicButton(25, 12)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

while True:
    screen.blit(quitButtonSurf.image,(0,0)) # you'll have to assign a location for this object, I set it to 0,0 simply for testing
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I hope this helped

Comment: This works well, I ended up doing this because maybe **Surface** can't be subclassed the same way you would subclass a **Sprite**.